# LibGdx Box2d collison not matching up with sprite

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I am making a game as a project for a college class. when my main character (the tree) hits the ground, it stops short of the ground

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05eYp.png)

and when the player lands on the little platform that gap is even bigger

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMPfL.png)

my code for creating the body of the character and and ground is this

```
public static Body createBody(int x, int y, float width, float height, boolean isStatic){
        Body body;

        BodyDef def = new BodyDef();

        if(isStatic){
            def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        }
        else {
            def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        }


        def.position.set(x / PPM , y / PPM);

        // returns a World object    
        body = GlobalWorld.getInstance().createBody(def);

        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();

        shape.setAsBox(width / 2 / PPM, height / 2 / PPM);

        body.createFixture(shape, 1.0f);

        shape.dispose();
        return body;
}
```

The code for the ground is in it's own class

```
public class Material {
    private Texture image;
    private Body body;
    private Sprite sprite;

    public Material(Texture t, int x, int y, int w, int h){
        image = t;
        sprite = new Sprite(t);
        body = BoxBuilder.createBody(x, y, w, h, true);
        body.setUserData("Ground");
    }

    public void draw(){
        // returns a SpriteBatch
        SpriteBatch batch = GlobalBatch.getInstance();
        sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x * PPM, body.getPosition().y * PPM);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }

    public void dispose(){
        image.dispose();
    }
}
```

the code for drawing the ground

```
public void draw(){
     for(Material m : worldObjects){
        m.draw();
     }
}
```

my code for drawing the character

```
public void create(){
    // do stuff

    // global vars
    body = createBody(0, 480, 313, 260, false);

    texture = new Texture("tree.PNG");
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);

    // do stuff
}

public void render(){
    // do stuff
    sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x*PPM, body.getPosition().y*PPM);
    batch.begin()
    sprite.draw(batch)
    batch.end()
    // do stuff
}
```

and PPM(Pixel per Meter) is

```
public static final float PPM = 32;
```

I don't know what is the problem here, I want the character to land on the ground, not land above it. So if someone could tell me what's causing this or point me to a good tutorial for learning more about box2d I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe the canvas size is bigger than the image. make sure the height of the canvas and the image is equal.

Comment: the ground is made up of individaul tiles, and doesn't libgdx take care of the canvas for me? I don't know what you mean by your suggestion

Comment: use `Box2DDebugRenderer` and check bound of your body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we create body with `PolygonShape` then body is at the center of that Polygon so when draw with body position it starts drawing from center of `PolygonShape` so we need to draw at left bottom corner.

In **Material** class

replace

```
sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x * PPM, body.getPosition().y * PPM);
```

with

```
sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x*PPM-sprite.getWidth()/2,body.getPosition().y-sprite.getHeight()/2);
sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle()*MathUtils.radDeg);
```

And for **Character** draw also change

```
sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x*PPM, body.getPosition().y*PPM);
```

with

```
sprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x*PPM-sprite.getWidth()/2, body.getPosition().y*PPM-sprite.getHeight()/2);
sprite.setRotation(body.getAngle()*MathUtils.radDeg);
```

---

As I see in your code you're not setting size of `Sprite` in `Material` class as well as for Character so set width and height.

In Material Class

```
sprite = new Sprite(t);
sprite.setSize(w,h);
```

And for Character

```
body = createBody(0, 480, 313, 260, false);
texture = new Texture("tree.PNG");
sprite = new Sprite(texture);
sprite.setSize(313,260);
```